# RealmChangeListener Or OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener?

Tags: android, realm

What is the difference between the `RealmChangeListener` and the `OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RealmChangeListener<T>` receives only the element the change occurred on, like `Realm`, `RealmResults` or `RealmObject`

But `OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener<T>` can only be added to `RealmResults`/`RealmList`, however it also provides you with `OrderedRealmCollectionChangeSet` which contains the exact position of where an item was inserted, modified or deleted.

There is also `RealmObjectChangeListener` that you can add to `RealmObject` which receives the fields that have been modified.